# Improve Performance of Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

Currently I have a subquery, which in itself has a subquery within it.  Performance wise this isn't going to be great when I put this into my stored procedure.  I was wondering if there was any way I can improve the performance of this code, or look at different way of writing this?

Basically I'm looking up price data, but we only have a price record loaded into our warehouse if the price has changed.  So I need to look up the latest date per instrument that we have received a price and then return that price.  I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @EndDate    DATETIME

SET @EndDate = '2015-10-31'

SELECT                  
ip2.INSTR_ID
,   ip2.PRC_TMS
,   ip2.PRC_CURR_CDE
,   COALESCE(MAX(CASE 
                    WHEN ip2.PRC_TYP = 'CLO' THEN ip2.PRC_QUOTE_AMT 
                END),
        MAX(ip2.PRC_QUOTE_AMT)) AS PRC_QUOTE_AMT

FROM ISSUE_PRICE AS ip2

INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                INSTR_ID AS INSTR_ID
            ,   MAX(PRC_TMS) AS PRC_TMS

            FROM ISSUE_PRICE
            WHERE PRC_SRCE_TYP = 'SSC'
            AND PRC_TMS <= @EndDate
            AND PRC_TYP IN ('LST', 'CLO')
            GROUP BY INSTR_ID) AS i2
ON i2.INSTR_ID = ip2.INSTR_ID
AND i2.PRC_TMS = ip2.PRC_TMS

WHERE ip2.PRC_SRCE_TYP = 'SSC'
AND ip2.PRC_TYP IN ('LST', 'CLO')
GROUP BY ip2.PRC_TMS, ip2.INSTR_ID, ip2.PRC_CURR_CDE
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What I'd do first is look at the indexes that I have on those tables you're using, making sure statistics are up to date for those tables and then look to move the aggregation to as a higher level as possible, out of the inner parts. Also, look into using `EXISTS` clause yield in faster execution times. Most of the times it would be really helpful to offer some information about indexes on the tables as well as the amount of data in the tables you're querying, as a start.

Comment: [Retrieving n rows per group](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using `Row_Number` window function to identity the max `PRC_TMS` per `INSTR_ID`. Try this,

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY INSTR_ID
                    ORDER BY PRC_TMS DESC) AS rn,*
         FROM   ISSUE_PRICE
         WHERE  PRC_SRCE_TYP = 'SSC'
                AND PRC_TMS <= @EndDate
                AND PRC_TYP IN ( 'LST', 'CLO' ))
SELECT ip2.INSTR_ID,
       ip2.PRC_TMS,
       ip2.PRC_CURR_CDE,
       COALESCE(Max(CASE
                      WHEN ip2.PRC_TYP = 'CLO' THEN ip2.PRC_QUOTE_AMT
                    END), Max(ip2.PRC_QUOTE_AMT)) AS PRC_QUOTE_AMT
FROM   cte
WHERE  RN = 1
GROUP  BY ip2.PRC_TMS,
          ip2.INSTR_ID,
          ip2.PRC_CURR_CDE
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries do not necessarily lead to performance problems.  But, you can do what you want more efficiently and concisely by using window functions:

```
SELECT ip.INSTR_ID, ip.PRC_TMS, ip.PRC_CURR_CDE,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN ip.PRC_TYP = 'CLO' THEN ip.PRC_QUOTE_AMT 
                    END),
                MAX(ip.PRC_QUOTE_AMT)
               ) AS PRC_QUOTE_AMT    
FROM (SELECT ip.*,
             MAX(PRC_TMC) OVER (PARTITION BY INSTR_ID) as MAX_PRC_TMS
      FROM ISSUE_PRICE ip
      WHERE ip.PRC_SRCE_TYP = 'SSC' AND ip.PRC_TYP IN ('LST', 'CLO')
     ) ip
WHERE ip.PRC_TMS = ip.MAX_PRC_TMS
GROUP BY ip.PRC_TMS, ip.INSTR_ID, ip.PRC_CURR_CDE;
```